Возможно ли сделать upcast делегата Func<TIn, TOut>?
Упрощенный абстрактный пример. Есть ExceptionMapper, который должен  уметь настраивать маппинг SomeException -> SomeObj и конвертировать объект типа SomeException в JSON строку, представленную в виде объекта SomeObject. Код консольного приложения (.net-8) ниже.
Основная проблема - хранить маппинг для определенного Exception. Маппинг представлен делегатом
Func<T, TObj> mapFn where T: Exception where TObj: class. Я объявил словарь:
private static Dictionary<string, Func<Exception, object>> _map = new();

Казалось бы, что тип Exception шире, чем любой из возможных <T> where T: Exception. Также и object будет шире любого типа <TObj> where TObj: class, но такой upcast возвращает null:
public static void AddMapping<T, TObj>(Func<T, TObj> mapFn) where T: Exception where TObj: class
{
    _map.Add(typeof(T).Name, mapFn as Func<Exception, object>); // <-- Тут upcast возвращает null
}

Вопросы:

Почему такой upcast не срабатывает как ожидается?
Как изменить мой пример, чтобы ожидаемое поведение работало?


Полный код (можно вставить в Program.cs консольного приложения и запускать):
using System.Text.Json;

ExceptionMapper.AddMapping((ApplicationException ex) => new { Message = ex.Message });

var result = ExceptionMapper.MapToJson(new ApplicationException("App crushed"));

Console.WriteLine(result);

static class ExceptionMapper
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<Exception, object>> _map = new();
    
    public static void AddMapping<T, TObj>(Func<T, TObj> mapFn) where T: Exception where TObj: class
    {
        _map.Add(typeof(T).Name, mapFn as Func<Exception, object>); // <-- Тут upcast возвращает null
    }

    public static string MapToJson<T>(T ex) where T : Exception
    {
        if (!_map.TryGetValue(ex.GetType().Name, out var mapFn))
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(new {});
        }

        if (mapFn == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"mapFn is null for mapped exception {ex.GetType().Name}"); // <-- Бросится exception
        }

        var obj = mapFn(ex);
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
    }
}

Вывод в консоли:

Unhandled exception. System.Exception: mapFn is null for mapped
exception ApplicationException


Func<Exception, object> и Func<T, TObj> where T : Exception where TObj : class это два совершенно разных типа с точки зрения наследования. Всё что их объединяет это один и тот же шаблонный класс. Инстансы дженериковые классов с разными дженериковыми параметрами невозможно кастить друг в друга, даже если сами параметры являются наследником либо реализацией по отношению друг к другу

При этом превратить одно в другое можно создав новый экземляр нужного делегата, который просто вызовет первоначальный делегат с кастом параметров. Всё что вам нужно это лямбда в качестве второго параметра: _map.Add(typeof(T).Name, exception => mapFn((T)exception))

Однако также стоит понимать, что поскольку параметры давнкастятся при вызове, то есть из более общих кастятся к более конкретным, вы ответсвены за то, чтобы вызывать каждую из Func<> с правильными изначальными типами параметров, ведь теперь компилятор уже не подскажет об ошибке, и вы словите её лишь в рантайме

@iikuzmychov спасибо за разъяснение. Но мне все равно не понятно, что тогда означает Func<in TIn, out TOut>. Я ожидал, что ковариантность и контвариантность generic параметров как раз и предполагает, что я могу присвоить менее обобщенный делегат более обобщенному. Но видимо, по каким-то причинам это не так. Пойду разбираться в этой теме

@iikuzmychov и по  поводу downcast. У меня его вроде бы нет в моем примере, так что опасаться нечего, верно?

Ну вообще, вы правы. Эти параметры ко- и контрвариативные, я забыл об этом, стоит пояснить с учётом этого. Тут дело в следующем: TIn контрвариативен, а TOut ковариативен и это их существенно отличает. В то время как ковариативность подразумевает возможность приведения к базовому типу. Например, вы можете заапкастить Func в Func. И это логично, ведь если вы на выход ожидаете object, то нет никаких проблем, если вам вернут его наследника T

Приэтом контравариантность подразумевает обратное, например, вы можете задаункастить Action к Action. И в данном случае это будет безопасно, поскольку этот тип является типом входного параметра функции. А раз функция может обрабатывать параметр object, то и его наследника int без ошибок обработает

Вы же пытаетесь привести Func<TException, TObject> в Func<Exception, object>. Такое было бы возможно только в том случае если бы оба параметра были ковариативными, но это не так. С приведением TObject в object никаких проблем нет. А вот с TException в Exception проблемка. Если ваш метод ожидает что ему на вход поступит конкретная ошибка, но вместо этого ему передадут Exception, то у неё класса может не быть некоторых полей или методов той конкретной TException с которой умеет работать метод

По этому вам нужно либо вручную кастить параметры с использованием лямбды, как я показал либо же вовсе поменять Func<TException, TObject> на <Exception, TObject>. С учётом логики вашего класса, второе не есть возможным. При этом при использовании первого варианта, за счёт сопоставления каждого обработчика ошибки с названием ошибки, вы тем самым  обеспечиваете правильную логику работы
